# Extract values of the object received in the apex method!

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, json, javascript-controller

I am passing in an object with mutiple rows of data, which eventually will be saved to the custom object. How do I extract the values of the object that I received in Aura enabled apex method.
[image]
Controller js:

```
var mduReport = [];
var allUnits = component.get("v.mduInfo");        
for (let i=0; i < allUnits.length; i++) {
     var mdu = {};
     mdu["streetAddress"] = allUnits[i].address.Name;            
     mdu["totalUnits"] = allUnits[i].totalUnits;
     mduReport.push(mdu);
  } 
  helper.savePenReport(component, mduReport);
```

Helper JS

```
savePenReport : function(component, mdus) {  
        //console.log()
        var penReport = component.get("c.savePenReport");
        var jsonMdus = JSON.stringify(mdus);
        penReport.setParams({ mdus : jsonMdus });   
        penReport.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();           
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
            }else
                alert(state);                  
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(penReport); 
    }
```

Apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void savePenReport(String mdus) {
    Object[] values = (Object[])System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(mdus);
    for( Object o : values) {
        system.debug(o);
    }
    system.debug(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct answer, you can cast the Object to a `Map<String, Object>` to read the data:

```
for( Object o : values) {
    Map<String, Object> row = (Map<String, Object>)o;
    system.debug(row.get('streetAddress'));
}
```

---

If you make a "wrapper" class, you can pass in the data directly without messing about with JSON:

```
public class MDU {
  @AuraEnabled public Integer aaUnits;
  @AuraEnabled public Integer ccUnits;
  @AuraEnabled public Integer internetOffering;
  @AuraEnabled public Integer nnUnits;
  @AuraEnabled public Integer phoneOffering;
  @AuraEnabled public String streetAddress;
  ...
}
@AuraEnabled public static void savePenReport(MDU[] mdus) {
  ...
```

Your parameters would then simply be:

```
penReport.setParams({ mdus : mdus });
```

---

## Side Note

Your JavaScript can be written simply as:

```
var mduReport = component.get("v.mduInfo").map(
  function(mdu) {
    return { streetAddress: mdu.address.Name, totalUnits: mdu.totalUnits };
  }
);
```